# Bash script to check for diff

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to get this script to work for checking the output of a program (test21) against known correct result text files. I've tried playing around with a couple ways of writing it, but I can't get it to work. Any ideas, thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                        

arr=$(find resultfile*)
x=0


for i in $(find resultfile*);do
arr[$x]=$i
x=$(($x + 1))
done

for i in ${arr[@]}; do
echo $i
done

x=0
for i in $(find testfile*);
do
    if diff  ${arr[$x]} <(./test21< testfile1.txt 2>&1); then
        echo Everything is correct
    else
        echo Everything is wrong
    fi
    x=$(($x+1))

done
```

It says for this,I get:

```
Segmentation fault: 11  ./test21 < "testfile1.txt" 2>&1
```

My program `test21` takes in an input text file and parses it, which could result in the segmentation faults. But if I use `./test21 testfile1.txt` my program runs perfectly fine. I hardcoded in `testfile1.txt`, but it should be

```
if diff  ${arr[$x]} <(./test21< $i 2>&1); then
```

However, it's reading it as `$i`, even if I do `"$i"`.

Comment: What does it do instead?

Comment: And what does `./test21` do?

Comment: Added edits at the end

Comment: I am not sure I totally understand the problem, but I wrote a script that had to do a similar thing recently. Instead I did `diff reference.out test.out > diff.log` and then checked `if [ -s diff.log ]; then` ... Dunno if that helps.

Comment: You say `./test21 testfile1.txt` works OK, but you are invoking it as `./test21 <testfile1.txt` (albeit with different spacing) so you are not giving the program an `argv[1]`.  Does your program validate its arguments before trying to use them?  I suspect that is your trouble.

Comment: `(./test21< testfile1.txt 2>&1)` You are running the previous statement in a subshell and are redirecting the file `testfile1.txt` to `./test21`, then redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` while still in the subshell, then you attempt to redirect `stdout` from the subshell to be the second are along with `${arr[$x]}` to diff. Are you sure that is what you want? Why are you redirecting the file `testfile1.txt` to `./test21` instead of just calling `./test21 testfile1.txt` ??

Comment: Also it certainly looks like you intend `arr=( $(find resultfile*) )` instead of `arr=$(find resultfile*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get:
>
> ```
> Segmentation fault: 11  ./test21 < "testfile1.txt" 2>&1
> ```
>
> My program `test21` takes in an input text file and parses it, which
>   could result in the segmentation faults. But if I use `./test21 testfile1.txt` my program runs perfectly fine.

Then just use that; instead of

```
./test21< testfile1.txt 2>&1
```

write

```
./test21 testfile1.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you want to run a program `myprogram` which will use `input.txt` file as input.
You want to compare output of your program with some known correct result which is written in `correct.txt` file. We will save output of your program in `actual.txt` file.

```
#!/bin/bash
./myprogram < input.txt > actual.txt
cmp -s actual.txt correct.txt
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "WRONG"
else
   echo "CORRECT"
fi
```

Note that `actual.txt` will capture only output that came from `stdout`. If out want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` you then want to use this command:

```
./myprogram < input.txt &> actual.txt
```

If you want to ignore `stderr` and throw it in "black hole" you will use:

```
./myprogram < input.txt 2> /dev/null > actual.txt
```